# IInputConnectionWrapper: showStatusIcon on inactive InputConnection

Tags: android

I'm getting the warning "IInputConnectionWrapper: showStatusIcon on inactive InputConnection" when shutting down my app.

After looking at the [code](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/com/android/internal/view/IInputConnectionWrapper.java) (line 406) that generates this warning, it looks like this is somehow related putting my app in Full Screen mode. The code that sets my Activity to Full Screen is:

```
getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

Also of note is that I only see the warning when testing on my Nexus 7, which has touch screen menu buttons on the bottom of the screen. My Droid X, which has physical menu buttons, does not incur this warning.

Am I using the wrong setting to put the App in full screen mode? Or am I completely off in what's causing this obscure warning?